# Android Studio не видит SDK

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, mac

Ставлю на свой mac m1 Android Studio последней версии, после запуска он пишет что отсутствует SDK, предлагает его скачать, но не скачивает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдает такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Через SDK Manager все тоже самое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильную ли версию Android Studio скачали с сайта? Там есть 2 варианта, для Intel-процессоров и для Apple-процессоров.

Comment: Да, версия для АРМ. Хотя пока танцевал с бубном пробовал и интоловскую версию, она себя так же ведёт